# android: best practice for custom background

Tags: android, image, background

I am new to android but an experienced Java and other languages programmer.

I need to create a custom background for the initial app activity. It's quite simple, here it is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLUtk.jpg

Should be pretty simple!
The best I could come up with is:

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

First, this was driving me crazy, I was always getting:

```
Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Searching, first hints pointed to a size issue - but the file size is 11kB! Then I found more hits and they essentially pointed to **resolution**. My image dimensions were 1080x1920px. I resized it to 768px (keeping ratio) and - voilá! - now it loaded.

However, I wonder if this is the correct approach. After many years of web development, I wonder if a "css-like" approach would be more suitable. If I use that image size, will it work fine for all devices and all resolutions? After all, it's just two colors (granted, with a curved element).

What are best practices for such cases? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practices for this come in understanding the following 3 parts of application development and design: [how to handle bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), [how to provide resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html), and [who is the target for your app](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Starting at who is the target of your app is not just the person but the devices they tend to use and the devices you want to support. In your question you mentioned that resizing the image to 768px prevented the error from occurring but that error happened because 1080 (at 16:9) resolution are rather large images when decompressed. So your own development device is not capable of handling a rather large image. Which is 8M when decompressed as ARGB, the 768px image is just above 4MB. So you can see that there is a significant memory difference. In addition to considering memory sizes you may consider screen size differences, image for a moment if you had a 800x480 image being displayed on a very capable 2048x1536 display, not considering memory usage a scaled image would look very jagged and the aspect ratio would be flawed, even worse would be if the device's orientation changed.

The conclusion is to provide the graphics for the kind of devices you want to support. Providing these resources is a matter of understanding how apps organize their resources.

Comment: ok, so it looks there is no "css-like" way - it's providing images for all the devices I want to support.

Answer (score 2):

See this:
 https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

You should create diferent bitmaps for diferent resolution and screen density.